# How to include any template using Shortcode fuction?

Tags: functions, shortcode, templates, child-theme

```
function custom_code(){
    return include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom-template.php');
}
add_shortcode('custom_shortcode','custom_code');
```

As you can check above I want to include a template using shortcode how to make it done?

Comment: Please check once **https://gist.github.com/germanny/9420496**

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the `include` statement. And you shouldn't use `include` template parts.

And here's how to do it correctly:

```
function custom_code() {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'custom-template.php' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_shortcode', 'custom_code' );
```

So what we're doing here is:

1. Start output buffering.
2. Include given template part using [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function.
3. Return all the output generated by that template and delete the buffer.